# How to generalize the summation

Tags: summation

For some work of mine, I came out with following terms for the value $m$, where $m$ is even.

For $m=6$ :  ${}\quad 1 + 6 + \{5+4+3+2+1\} + \{4+3+2+1\} = 32$

For $m=8$ : ${}\quad 1 + 8 + \{7+6+5+4+3+2+1\} + [\{6+5+4+3+2+1\}+ \{5+4+3+2+1\} + \{4+3+2+1\} + \{3+2+1\}+ \{2+1\} + \{1\}] + [\{5+4+3+2+1\} + \{4+3+2+1\} + \{ 3+2+1 \}+ \{2+1\} + \{1\}]= 128$

I want to generalize this summation. I got it upto third term in the series but not able to get it. I got the following:

$$1 + m + \sum_{i=m-1}^1 i.$$

Not able to find for the terms inside the big bracket. Kindly help. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks for the help.

***more detail*** : The second term satisfy the property, let me name it as $1e$. The third terms in bracket satisfy the property $2e$. The fourth term inside the brackets [ ] for $m=8$ satisfy the property $3e$ and so on. Every series will to the final property i.e. $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does your expression for $m=6$ stop at the sum $\{4+3+2+1\}$? Why doesn't it go all the way down to
$$\cdots+\{3+2+1\}+\{2+1\}+\{1\}$$
like with $m=8$?

Comment: The fact that the **name** of the property is "1e" or "2e" or anything else doesn't tell us what the property ***is***.

Comment: Actually this is related with number of ways in arranging a m-tuple with odd and even numbers. My arrangement is like that a tuple with exactly one even number at $k^{th}$ position and its complement i.e tuple with exactly one odd number at $k^{th}$ position lie in 1st group, I named it satisfying property $1e$, and so on....and I got that this runs upto $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$ position.

Comment: Monalisa, it seems to me that you really want to just calculate the number of ways of marking at most $k$ slots in an array of length $m=2k$ to be reserved for even numbers (and the rest are to be reserved for odd numbers). With some kind of furter way of equating any $k+k$ even/odd split with its complementary split. Effectively you are then calculating the number of ways of splitting a group of $m$ people into two teams (with unspecifed number of people in a single team). The answer to that is clearly $2^{m-1}$ - fitting the data you gave. But I don't understand what goes into the brackets.

Comment: actually sir in the brackets its the number of tuples satisfying so. For that I attached two images showing arrangements done by me by placing even (e) and odd (o) numbers at different positions.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that you're looking at
$$\begin{align*}
1+m&+\bigl\{(m-1)+(m-2)+\cdots+2+1\bigr\}\\
&+\bigl\{(m-2)+\cdots+2+1\bigr\}\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&+\{2+1\}\\
&+\{1\}
\end{align*}$$
which would be captured in your summation notation as
$$1+m+\sum_{n=m-1}^1\left(\sum_{i=n}^1i\right)$$
Here's a closed-form formula for it:
$$\begin{align*}
1+m+\sum_{n=m-1}^1\left(\sum_{i=n}^1i\right)&=1+m+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\right) \\\\
&=1+m+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right) \\\\
&=1+m+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n^2\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n\right)\\\\
&=1+m+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2m^3-3m^2+m}{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{m^2-m}{2}\right)\\\\
&=1+m+\frac{2m^3-3m^2+m}{12}+\frac{m^2-m}{4} \\\\
&=\frac{12}{12}+\frac{12m}{12}+\frac{2m^3-3m^2+m}{12}+\frac{3m^2-3m}{12}\\\\
&=\frac{2m^3+10m+12}{12} 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Am thankful for your answer sir, but I want to generalize this summation term for other values of $m$ too.... A general summation series to represent the series for any even value of $m$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the **definition** of the series is that you're looking at.

Comment: Sir, can you solve it for the series meant for $m=8$?

Comment: @monalisa provided answer is general, just replace m=8 into it and u get the sum.

Comment: @SAAN you are right but its not giving the required sum in the end

Comment: @monalisa yes, please see this solution provide you sum 93+sum of next square bracket which is 35. So you get 128.